# How is a vector of a sentence related to the vectors of its components?

Tags: python, tensorflow, vector, components, sentence

Let's say we have an English sentence - *Mr. Johnson is a coder*. And we calcuate its vector - `v0` - by using an encoder, say *MUSE* (https://pypi.org/project/muse-as-service/). And then using this same encoder, we calculate the vectors for *"Mr. Johnson is"* and *"a coder."*, respectively, as `v1` and `v2`. My question is, how is `v0` related to `v1` and `v2`? (I have tried `numpy.add` for `v1` and `v2` and got `v12`, and then tried `numpy.inner` for `v12` and `v0`, and the result did not really make sense to me.)

You can download two txt files from the following OneDrive link to see the sample sentence/components and their 512-dimentional vectors, as calculated by the above mentioned MUSE tool:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqMx36ZH6wJMhct5emETk9795Clyeg?e=PN2RgN

Comment: I don't understand what it means to "calculate the vector of a sentence". What would be the value of v0 in your example?

Comment: Samples provided.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.